# Why I am getting these errors when I execute Heroku CLI commands?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I am getting this kind of error when I execute any commands of Heroku such as `heroku -v` or `heroku login`.

> 'crumb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.
>
> 'ruby.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your errors complains about Ruby not being available. Based on that message I suspect you have the [legacy Ruby-based CLI](https://github.com/heroku/legacy-cli) installed. It hasn't been supported [for a very long time](https://github.com/heroku/legacy-cli/releases).

Remove it and then install [the current CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli), which is built with Node.js.